# A.N.T landscape erosion: weightmaps only

Tags: mesh, add-on

The built-in A.N.T Landscape generation has an Erosion option, which applies the effects of water erosion to the landscape.

It generates useful vertex groups showing where the water would go, etc. Is it possible to only generate the vertex groups, but without applying the erosion effects (ie. in a way that doesn't change the mesh)?